# pass dynamic data to jqplot piechart in ASP.net

Tags: spagobi

pass dynamic data to jqplot piechart in ASP.net

Chandra

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use SpagoBI server without using Cubes. Many different reporting engines plug into SpagoBI.  I'm primarily using BIRT reports in SpagoBI, using a traditional RDMS model.

Look at the following list for the list of supported analytic engines, aside from the OLAP category.
http://www.spagoworld.org/xwiki/bin/view/SpagoBI/AnalyticalEngines

Answer (score 0):

See here for the docs on settings up a Data Source in SpagoBI 
http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_server/Data+Source

See these two screenshots for how to the the Data Source settings for a JTDS Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Connection. You can set it up via JNDI, as well.

SpagoBI Data Source menu : http://www.davidbharrison.com/?p=138
SpagoBI JTDS MSSql JDBC Data source settings:  http://www.davidbharrison.com/?p=137

Remember to copy the jtds (or MS Equivalent) JDBC jar into your app server's library folder, SpagoBI libs, or class path. Be sure to test the data source and then save it. You'll have to restart the app server or app after that.